# Opencv Capture Causes Memory Allocation Error

Tags: c, memory-management, opencv, capture

I have implemented a capture code runs on OpenCV libraries. Code captures from 2 cameras order by order. But the code causes memory allocation error after a while.

I have to release a capture stream of camera1 to open a capture stream of camera2. I could not able to get two capture simultanously so I have to capture it order by order.

Why it couses memory allocation error in this scenario?

My code is located below:

```
#include <cv.h>
#include <highgui.h>
#include <cxcore.h>
#include <stdio.h>

  CvCapture* camera; // Use the default camera
  IplImage*     frame;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{    

     while(1)
     {
      camera = cvCreateCameraCapture(0); // Use the default camera
      //camera2 = cvCreateCameraCapture(1); // Use the default camera
      frame = 0;
      //frame2 = 0;

      cvSetCaptureProperty(camera,CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH,1024) ;
      cvSetCaptureProperty(camera,CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT,768); 

      frame = cvQueryFrame(camera); //need to capture at least one extra frame

      if (frame != NULL) {
        printf("Frame extracted from CAM1\n\r");
            cvSaveImage("/dev/shm/webcam1.jpg", frame,0);
        printf("Frame from CAM1 saved\n\r");
      } else {
          printf("Null frame 1\n\r");
      }

      cvReleaseImage(&frame);
      cvReleaseCapture(&camera);

      camera = cvCreateCameraCapture(1); // Use the default camera

      cvSetCaptureProperty(camera,CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH,1024) ;
      cvSetCaptureProperty(camera,CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT,768); 

      frame = cvQueryFrame(camera); //need to capture at least one extra frame

      if (frame != NULL) {
        printf("Frame extracted from CAM2\n\r");
            cvSaveImage("/dev/shm/webcam2.jpg", frame,0);
        printf("Frame from CAM2 saved\n\r");
      } else {
          printf("Null frame 2\n\r");
      }
      cvReleaseImage(&frame);
      cvReleaseCapture(&camera);
    }
```

Comment: May I suggest to try to do half your code at once? Try to find if you can reproduce the problem with one camera, then the other. Create yourself a simple method to which you can pass the camera #. And by memory allocation error you mean a memory leak?

Comment: If I just try half of code at one and release capture at the out of while loop it works like a charm. But in this case it does not. And yes i mean a memory leak.

Comment: Maybe it takes a bit to release the driver and you are creating a leak by using the same variables, call the "allocateAndGrab" method to encapsulate your code. At least you will have a a different stack for each set of variables.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can start declaring out of while() statement the cameraCapture:

```
 camera0 = cvCreateCameraCapture(0);
 camera1 = cvCreateCameraCapture(1);
 frame0 = 0;
 frame1 = 0;
 cvSetCaptureProperty(camera0,CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH,1024) ;
 cvSetCaptureProperty(camera0,CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT,768);
 cvSetCaptureProperty(camera1,CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH,1024) ;
 cvSetCaptureProperty(camera1,CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT,768); 

 while(1) {
     /* your operation */
     frame0 = cvQueryFrame(camera0);
     frame1 = cvQueryFrame(camera1);
     /* your operation */
 }

 cvReleaseImage(&frame0);
 cvReleaseImage(&frame1);
 cvReleaseCapture(&camera0);
 cvReleaseCapture(&camera1);
```

## Edit

If you want to take first stream from A-cam and then from B-cam, you'll have a code like the this. I don't understand exactly what do you want to do, so this code simply show your stream on a window.
Remember to use **cvWaitKey(...)** in order to give to highgui time to process the draw requests from **cvShowImage()**.
Also, take a look at the [documentation](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/c/highgui_reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#cvSetCaptureProperty) of **cvSetCaptureProperty**: here is written that currently the function supports only video files:

- CV_CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC;
- CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES;
- CV_CAP_PROP_POS_AVI_RATIO.

By the way, this is my suggest:

```
const char* wndName = "window";
cvNamedWindow(wndName, CV_WINDOW_NORMAL);

IplImage* frame;
CvCapture* capture;

while(true) {
  capture = cvCaptureFromCAM(0);

  /* Showing for a while capture in window */
  while(/* your condition */) {
    frame = cvQueryFrame(capture);
    /* operation with A cam */
    cvShowImage(wndName, frame);
    cvWaitKey(30);
  }

  cvReleaseCapture(&capture);
  cvWaitKey(100);
  /* switching source cam */
  capture = cvCaptureFromCAM(1);

  /* Showing for a while capture in the same window */
  while(/* your condition */) {
    frame = cvQueryFrame(capture);
    /* operation with B cam */
    cvShowImage(wndName, frame);
    cvWaitKey(30);
  }
} 
cvReleaseImage(&frame); 
cvReleaseCapture(&capture);
```

This works for me, give me any feedback.

Comment: In this case you have to allocate bandwith for both two cameras' stream. But in my code, I allocate bandwith for just one camera stream for a certain time. In total my computer does not have enaugh sources to take dual stream simulatanously.

Comment: Sorry, I haven't understand that your problem is that you not have enough resources to take dual stream simultaneously. So, let me understand: have you attacked the two webcam (A and B) to the PC? And want you take some frame from A and, after a while, take some frame from B?

Comment: thank you for the efford but firstly your edited code is not clear. camera1 and camera2 is undeclared.  I can not be working because you did not assigned captures to cameras (for example camera0 = cvCreateCameraCapture(0))
In the second comment you defined my algorithm well. But we should edit it as follow:

I have attached the two webcam (A and B) to the PC. And want you take some frame from A and, after a while, take some frame from B. I want to repeat this action(take some frame from A and, after a while, take some frame from B) forewer.

Thank you.